How to Set Up a Webhook for WhatsApp Template Status Updates?
After creating a WhatsApp template, is there a way to set up a webhook to receive the status updates of the template?

I'm happy to provide you with a solution now. It is possible: For this, you need to navigate the Manage Alarms page. There, you can hit the Create Alarm button and use any of the following codes to specify what you need:

63041 (paused)
63042 (disabled)
63040 (rejected)
63046 (Approved template)

From here, you can configure the alarm as desired. E.g. like this one here:

